# How do I catch the response of a script from another website in Javascript (it returns plain text)?

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I am using the following external script.

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org"> </script>
```

It replies with the client IP address in plain text. I have tried to get it working using the [available](https://www.ipify.org/) JSON response types and can catch the data via a callback. However, when I try to only get the plain text I am unable to work out how parse this data, I just keep getting an "Unexpected number" error. Is it possible to retrieve the information and store it without a callback?

Comment: if you have code which isn't working please show it. Note that this remote site isn't a script, it simply returns some plain text. There's nothing to execute, so putting it in a `<script` tag doesn't make much sense. It's not serving a JavaScript file. More likely you could just make an ajax request to it, assuming it allows CORS requests

Comment: What is the value of the parameter in your callback function?

Comment: Actually, https://www.ipify.org/ actually has a full Javascript example of how to use it. You really just need to follow that, it isn't complicated. What you've shown above is simply ignoring half the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load plain text as JavaScript code.  Don't do that.  The browser will try to parse and execute the response as JavaScript and then throw an error because the syntax is incorrect.

Instead, use any sort of AJAX API that will allow you to make a request to the endpoint and use the data.

For example, using [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```js
fetch("https://api.ipify.org")
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

There are many other ways to make AJAX requests:

- [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)
- [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

and a slew of other ways that all do the same thing.  The basic thing to understand is that you need to make a request to go get the resource, instead of trying to load it as a JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is by requesting it as a JSONP, which offers a callback function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org/?format=jsonp&callback=someName"></script>
```

when it loads, it'll invoke a function on window scope called `someName`, which will receive an object with the property `ip`.

Of course, there are better ways. For example, jQuery's `$.ajax` supports JSONP (alias `$.getJSON`) and has success/failure handlers, `fetch()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can get IP using this script

```js
async function getIP() {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
        const jsonObj = (res.json()).then(data => alert(data.ip));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

getIP();
```

I hope I got what you meant and answered you.